# Filter sub document array in Mongoose and return only matching elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've `UserSchema` that looks like this

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
    unique: 1
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 6
  },
  token: {
    type: String
  },
  role: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0 // 0 is student, 1 is admin
  },
  files: [FileSchema],
  internships: [InternshipSchema]
});
```

As can be seen , `files` and `internships` are subdocuments. My goal is to filter either of them based on specific input, e.g I would like to filter internships based on country.

However, I'm having a problem of returning only elements that match the search, I can only return all the elements, regardless of search filters being passed in.

I tried to refer [querying-subdocument-and-returning-matching-subdocument-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34218513/querying-subdocument-and-returning-matching-subdocument-only), but could not get it working.

My current code looks like this

```
app.get("/api/getInternships", (req, res) => {
  User.aggregate(
    {
      $match: {
        "internships.country": req.query.country
      }
    },
    { $unwind: "internships" },
    {
      $match: {
        "internships.country": req.query.country
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try my code:

```
app.get("/api/getInternships", (req, res) => {
    User.aggregate(
        { $project: { internships: 1 } },
        // after $project
        /* 
        {_id: ObjectId01, internships: [{country: 1}, {country: 2},...]}
        ....
         */
        { $unwind: '$internships' },
        // after $unwind
        /* 
        {_id: ObjectId01, internships: {country: 1}}
        {_id: ObjectId01, internships: {country: 2}}
        ...
         */
        {
            $match: {
                "internships.country": req.query.country
            }
        }
        // final result: [{_id: ObjectId01, internships: {country: 2}}, ...]
    ).exec((err, internships) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(internships);
        // [{_id: ObjectId01, internships: {country: 2}}, ...]
        // send data to client
        res.status(200).json(internships);
    });
});
```

Comment: Do we need any callback or something that will actually return the result ? Cuz if I test it like this with Postman, it has no response. I'm beginner as well, so something that might seem obvious, isn't obvious to me :P

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot :D
Also, this unwind feature is outsdanding!

Comment: hi. what's the additional code to only output internships as array. if i add $project _id: 0, and if i want to output all internships in the array, the output of your current code will be [ { internship: { internship object }} ] instead of [ {internship object} ]

Comment: @chitgoks have you managed to get that format